# How to get the bit position of any member in structure

Tags: c, arm

How can I get the bit position of any members in structure?

In example>

```
typedef struct BitExamStruct_
{
    unsigned int v1: 3;
    unsigned int v2: 4;
    unsigned int v3: 5;
    unsigned int v4: 6;
} BitExamStruct;
```

Is there any macro to get the bit position of any members like GetBitPos(v2, BitExamStruct)?

I thought that compiler might know members' location based on bits length in the structure. So I want to know whether I can get it by using just a simple macro without running code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by the naming of the member variables. Are bit1, .., bit4 supposed to be exactly one bit in size, or is bit1 supposed to be 3 bits in size, bit2 4 bits in size, bit3 5 bits in size and bit4 6 bits in size?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. It just a name. bit1 has 3 bits, bit2 4 bits. Something like that. I changed member's name.

Comment: Then I believe [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) is what you are looking for.

Comment: offsetof gives byte offset not bit offset

Comment: Yes, it's just a building block to the solution, not the solution itself. You'll also have to add a little bit of bit fiddling.

Comment: @rwols: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h> 3
The macros are
NULL
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and
offsetof(type, member-designator) [...] (If the
specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)*

Comment: @EOF I guess I learned something today!

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way that I know of to do so, but it doesn't mean you can't find a solution.

The following is not the prettiest code ever; it's a kind of hack to identify where the variable "begins" in memory. Please keep in mind that the following can give different results depending on the endianess:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_toto
{
  int a:2;
  int b:3;
  int c:3;    
} t_toto;

int
main()
{
  t_toto toto;
  unsigned char *c;
  int bytes;
  int bits;

  memset(&toto, 0, sizeof(t_toto));
  toto.c = 1;
  c = (unsigned char *)&toto;
  for (bytes = 0; bytes < (int)sizeof(t_toto); bytes++)
    {
      if (*c)
        break;
    }
  for (bits = 0; bits < 8; bits++)
    {
      if (*c & 0b10000000)
        break;
      *c = (*c << 1);
    }
  printf("position (bytes=%d, bits=%d): %d\n", bytes, bits, (bytes * 8) + bits);
  return 0;
}
```

What I do is that I initialize the whole structure to 0 and I set 1 as value of the variable I want to locate. The result is that only one bit is set to 1 in the structure. Then I read the memory byte per byte until I find one that's not zero. Once found, I can look at its bits until I find the one that's set.

Comment: Interesting.  The `0b10000000` notation is a non-standard extension in C (C++ has standardized it, though).  Much more significantly, you have to have the `toto.c` reference to make this work, which means you can't do the job generically.  Your code works for `toto.c`; it has to be revised to set `toto.b` or `toto.a` .  But it is better than nothing, which is the alternative that the standard provides.  Bit fields are one of the most arcane parts of standard C, and almost all the behaviour is implementation defined.

Comment: `(bytes * 8) + bits` is a little-endian byte, big endian bit  indexing.  I'd favor a consistent endian numbering like little-little.  Bonus `0b10000000` --> `1`

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable (aka standard C) way. But thinking outside the box, if you need full control or need this information badly, bitfields are the wrong approach. The proper solution is shifting and masking. Of course this is feasible only when you are in control of the source code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The tool makes header files of hardware registers in my company. Usually, I define bit positions for bit fields which I really need. But everytime hardware register spec. is changed, it happens.

Comment: Then you probably don’t care about portability and you might be able to find this information in your compiler ABI documentation.