# How to ensure that the members of a bit-field are at the same position of the underlying type or that member of bit-field is at exact position

Tags: c++, bit-fields, static-assert

I wonder if it is possible the make a compile-time check to verify, that the members in two different bit-fields hold the same position. The exact position is irrelevant.

```
struct A {
    uint8_t x : 1;
};
struct B {
    uint8_t y : 1;
};
static_assert(position_check<A, B>::value); // ?
```

Is this possible in any way?

Or, check if a member of the bit-field occupies known bit positions.

Comment: Not sure if this addresses your problem, but you could add an explicit, zero-length bitfield (like `uint8_t : 0`) immediately before any field you want to be 'aligned' - this will, at least, ensure they are both aligned to a `uint8_t` boundary.

Comment: Maybe see also here: [How to get the bit position of any member in structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622253/how-to-get-the-bit-position-of-any-member-in-structure).

Comment: The alignment is not the problem. I want to ensure that A::x is in position 0 of the underlying byte.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: I want to check this for µC register access, where bit-positin is relevant. I want to make a compile-time check, if the implementation-defined bit-position is correct.